FATAL: the ConfigMap "kubeadm-config" in the "kube-system" namespace was not found
I recently upgraded kubeadm, kubelet and kube ctl to v 1.30, and did a reinit for the cluster using
sudo kubeadm init phase kubeconfig admin --kubeconfig-dir /tmp/backup/kubelet/$NODE --apiserver-advertise-address $APIIP --cert-dir /etc/kubernetes/

When I issue
kubectl get nodes

I see my master and node 1 but the master still in the olders 1.26 version and state = NotReady

I tried
sudo kubeadm upgrade plan v1.30 --v=5

I get the following error

[upgrade/config] Use 'kubeadm init phase upload-config --config
your-config.yaml' to re-upload it. the ConfigMap "kubeadm-config" in
the "kube-system" namespace was not found
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade.enforceRequirements

When I issue
kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml

I see that there is this config file but not sure in the sahep of a file on the hard drive

kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml apiVersion: v1
data:   ClusterConfiguration: |
apiServer:
extraArgs:
authorization-mode: Node,RBAC
timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
clusterName: kubernetes
controllerManager: {}
dns: {}
etcd:
local:
dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
imageRepository: registry.k8s.io
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.26.4
networking:
dnsDomain: cluster.local
podSubnet: 10.10.0.0/16
serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
scheduler: {} kind: ConfigMap metadata:   creationTimestamp: "2023-04-14T14:47:57Z"   name: kubeadm-config   namespace: kube-system
resourceVersion: "224"   uid: db3c3f16-9b13-47c1-abfc-09a7322afbcd

So should I create a physical file and upload it? if yes, how please? Thanks in advance

Refer to this document and also go through this github issue which might be helpful for you.
